# How to deploy Rails app on subdomain root with Apache and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, deployment, passenger

I have working Rails app on sub-uri *redmine.example.org/redmine* and I want it on *redmine.example.org*

```
/var/www/work/redmine.src is approot
/var/www/work/redmine is symlink to /var/www/work/redmine.src/public

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/work
    ServerName redmine.example.org

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-access_log combined

    <Directory /var/www/work/redmine>
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    RackBaseURI /redmine
    <Directory /var/www/work/redmine.src>
            Options -MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried many combination and googled hours, but nothing works.

How should I change this config to deploy redmine on subdomain root?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it was easier, than I supposed.

When I read the manual again and again I found solution:
[link to manual](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2)

Now my config file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/work/redmine.src/public
    ServerName redmine.example.org

    <Directory /var/www/work/redmine.src/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deploy sub-uri app, might work for you too:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass /sub_uri/ http://localhost:8000/sub_uri/

    DocumentRoot /main_app/public
    <Directory /main_app/public>
       ...
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8000>
  DocumentRoot /sub_uri/public
  <Directory /sub_uri/public>
    ...
    SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT /sub_uri
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I don't have mod_proxy enabled, and I hope, there is nicer solution. But I'll try...

Answer (score 0):

I installed Redmine 3.3.1 on a Debian 9.0 Stretch server using the packages provided by the distribution itself (Apache + Redmine + Ruby + Rails + Passenger + MariaDB) more or less following those guides:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/InstallRedmineOnDebianStableApacheMysqlPassenger

I would like to leave `www.example.org` "for Apache" and `redmine.example.org` "for Redmine", so I ended up with the following setup.

I left `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` untouched and created a file named `redmine.conf` inside that same folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine.example.org
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
    <Directory /usr/share/redmine/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, I've linked it to the `sites-enabled` folder and restarted Apache:

```
# ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/redmine.conf
# systemctl restart apache2
```

To set up that virtual host, I followed the directions here:

- Deploying a Ruby application on Passenger + Apache

  - Deploying an app to a virtual host's root
    https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-virtual-host-s-root